# Inheritance and extension of models in c# with multiple implementations of property within base

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance

I have a pub/sub queue that returns what I'll call QueueMessages.

A QueueMessage has a Type and a Body. The type is always a string but the body varies depending on the type. I want the inheriting class to set the message type. I want to add my own local properties for storing on processing datatables.

I was hoping to be able to define a generic object for the body and override in the inheriting classes but it fails as I'm changing the return type.

Interface:

```
interface IBaseQueueMessage
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string MessageType { get; }
    object Message { get; set; }
    DateTime ConsumeDate { get; set; }
}
```

Base class:

```
public abstract class BaseQueueMessage:IBaseQueueMessage
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public abstract string MessageType { get; }
    public abstract object Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime ConsumeDate => DateTime.Now;
}
```

Inheriting Classes (there are 7 or 8 different ones in total)

```
public sealed class Type1Message: BaseCallType
{
    public override string MessageType => "Type1Message";
    public override Type1Message Message { get; set; }
}

public class Type1Message
{
    public string aaa { get; set; }
    public int bbb { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Type2Message: BaseCallType
{
    public override string MessageType => "Type2Message";
    public override Type2Message Message { get; set; }
}

public class Type2Message
{
    public string aaa { get; set; }
    public string bbb { get; set; }
    public int ccc {get; set;}
    public bool ddd {get; set;}
}
```

The above fails as I'm trying to return a specific class instead of the generic object.  I understand why it would fail, but I'd like to know what would be the correct way of doing this please?  I could just define individual classes for each and to hell with the interface and inheritance but it feels wrong to approach it that way.  I intend to map the QueueMessage directly onto the inheriting classes for each different type so I want the model to match exactly what I pick up from the queue.

Apologies in advance for probably missing something really obvious, it's been a while since I did any coding and this is a relatively new area to me.

**Edited to add more details on implementation problem**

Lots of this works, thanks. Where I still have a problem is in the MessageHandlerWrapper.  If I debug, then the handler object from the constructor that the method tries to use in `_handler = handler` is always null.

In my .net core startup.cs I have:

```
        void RegisterHandler<TMessageType, THandler>()
            where TMessageType : class
            where THandler : IMessageHandler<TMessageType>
        {
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<TMessageType>();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(
                serviceProvider => new MessageHandlerWrapper<TMessageType>(serviceProvider.GetService<THandler>(), serviceProvider)
            );
        }
```

...and it's the `...=> new MessageHandlerWrapper<...` near the end of that block that is resolved by the dependency when I'm debugging in the code mentioned above, so I can't see why the service isn't available at that point.

Is there some way I can manually try to debug this by resolving the service to a concrete handler in MessageHandlerWrapper to see where the problem may lie?

For completeness, the whole section in startup.cs is:

```
//set up message handlers
        var msgFactory = new MessageHandlerFactory();

        //create local function to make it easier to add service references
        void RegisterHandler<TMessageType, THandler>()
            where TMessageType : class
            where THandler : IMessageHandler<TMessageType>
        {
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<TMessageType>();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(
                serviceProvider => new MessageHandlerWrapper<TMessageType>(serviceProvider.GetService<THandler>(), serviceProvider)
            );
        }

        // Type1MessageHandler, etc is the implementation of IMessageHandler<Type1>
        RegisterHandler<Type1, Type1MessageHandler>();
        RegisterHandler<Type2, Type2MessageHandler>();
        RegisterHandler<Type3, Type3MessageHandler>();
        RegisterHandler<Type4, Type4MessageHandler>();

        // some string constants for message types would be better.
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMessageHandlerFactory>(serviceProvider =>
        {
            msgFactory.RegisterHandler("Type1",
                serviceProvider.GetService<MessageHandlerWrapper<Type1>>);
            msgFactory.RegisterHandler("Type2",
                serviceProvider.GetService<MessageHandlerWrapper<Type2>>);
            msgFactory.RegisterHandler("Type3",
                serviceProvider.GetService<MessageHandlerWrapper<Type3>>);
            msgFactory.RegisterHandler("Type4",
                serviceProvider.GetService<MessageHandlerWrapper<Type4>>);
            return msgFactory;
        });

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMessageHandler, MessageRouter>();
```

Comment: Given your interface declaration, the derived classes _must_ return type `object`. If you are willing/able to modify the interface so that it's generic, and the `Message` property can have type `T` (i.e. the interface type parameter), then each implementing class would be able to specify its own type. Unfortunately, it's not clear from your question what is possible here.

Comment: Thanks Peter. How would I change the message type in the interface as you suggest please?

Comment: See answer on marked duplicate. You may or may not need the non-generic base interface type shown in that answer, depending your exact scenario.

Comment: At some point you're going to need message handlers. How are you creating those? Are they resolved from an IoC container?

Comment: It's not clear whether this is relevant in your case, but I'm doing something similar with many different types of messages transmitted over a network. The header always has the same format, but the payload is completely different for each message type. My `Message` class has a `Memory<byte>` and a `GetPayload<T>` method where `T` is constrained to be a `struct`. The consumer checks the type value in the header and calls `GetPayload` with the appropriate type argument.

Comment: IMO the ideal situation is to end up with clean, type-safe message handler classes like `IMessageHandler<TMessage>`. Those classes will do the real work. Everything else is about getting the message to that class. From that standpoint I think it might be worth it if the code to "bridge" from non-generic `object` to `TMessage` might be worth it. I can offer some code, but the last step in the process depends on whether you're using IoC and if so, which one. It's a trade-off - some slightly complex and/or messy code which enables the message handlers to be type safe and testable.

Comment: @ScottHannen It's a proof of concept app really. It's using .net Core so the IoC is already built in. There's a consumer service declared within that that starts at startup and listens for incoming events on the queue. The service receives all message types, so it's on the "onMessageReceived" event that the first opportunity would arise to do something like, e.g. `If (msg.contains(\"MessageType\":\"MessageType1\") {do some stuff in MessageHandler(IMessageType<MessageType1>) }` if that's the sort of approach you mean?

Comment: That's part of what the unit test is for. If you want to resolve any issues along the way or just verify that it works, you can run and debug the unit test. It's faster, easier, and more focused than running the whole application. It's also better to ask new questions. These Q&As are meant to be useful to anyone who reads the question. But now the question that I answered isn't the same one you originally asked.

Comment: What is the exception you're getting?

Comment: There is no exception. As I said in the edited question, the handle that should be available in the constructor is just null. I take your point about extending the question, but as the code doesn't work as is, it makes it better to resolve it I think?  Anyhow, I'll try debugging the test but I don't think it will work in quite the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach. The intent of the design is to enable you to write type-safe generic message handler classes, but be able to call them when you're starting from a message of type `object`. Bridging from one to the other can be a pain, and I think it's at the heart of your question.

This doesn't use inheritance for the messages. (You mentioned you were open to not inheriting.) I don't think it would add any value in this scenario, although this could be adapted to use inheritance.

First, here's a generic `Message<T>` class. This doesn't replace your existing message class. It's just that in order to have a type-safe generic *handler*, you need a generic *message*.

```
public class Message<T>
{
    public Message(T content, Guid id, string messageType, DateTime consumeDate)
    {
        Content = content;
        Id = id;
        MessageType = messageType;
        ConsumeDate = consumeDate;
    }

    public T Content { get; }
    public Guid Id { get;  }
    public string MessageType { get; }
    public DateTime ConsumeDate { get;  }
}
```

Next, here's an interface for a message handler. The implementation doesn't matter for this example. What matters is that whatever `T` is, you can write a class to handle it.

```
public interface IMessageHandler<T> 
{
    void HandleMessage(Message<T> message);
}
```

This next interface and class are intended to serve as a "bridge" from your non-generic message (which uses `object`) to your generic message handler:

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
    void HandleMessage(IQueueMessage message);
}

public class MessageHandlerWrapper<TMessage> : IMessageHandler
{
    private readonly IMessageHandler<TMessage> _handler;

    public MessageHandlerWrapper(IMessageHandler<TMessage> handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    // This is the critical part - it gets us from object to TMessage.
    public void HandleMessage(IQueueMessage message)
    {
        _handler.HandleMessage(
            new Message<TMessage>(
                (TMessage)message.Message,
                message.Id,
                message.MessageType,
                message.ConsumeDate));
    }
}
```

Then you'll need a factory that returns the correct `IMessageHandler` depending on the message type string:

```
public interface IMessageHandlerFactory
{
    IMessageHandler GetHandler(string messageType);
}
```

Putting all of this together connects your non-generic message to your generic message handler:

```
public class MessageRouter : IMessageHandler
{
    private readonly IMessageHandlerFactory _messageHandlerFactory;

    public MessageRouter(IMessageHandlerFactory messageHandlerFactory)
    {
        _messageHandlerFactory = messageHandlerFactory;
    }

    public void HandleMessage(IQueueMessage message)
    {
        var handler = _messageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(message.MessageType);
        handler.HandleMessage(message);
    }
}
```

This class also implements `IMessageHandler`. It's going to take the message, without caring what the type is, use the factory to get a more specific handler, and route the message to that handler.

Now we need to implement the factory. Here's an implementation which will allow us to resolve handlers from an `IServiceProvider` without resorting to a service locator:

```
public class MessageHandlerFactory : IMessageHandlerFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<IMessageHandler>> _messageHandlers
        = new Dictionary<string, Func<IMessageHandler>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public void RegisterHandler(string messageType, Func<IMessageHandler> getHandlerFunction)
    {
        _messageHandlers[messageType] = getHandlerFunction;
    }

    public IMessageHandler GetHandler(string messageType)
    {
        if (_messageHandlers.ContainsKey(messageType))
            return _messageHandlers[messageType]();
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"No handler is registered for message type {messageType}.");
        // Or you could return some default handler that does something else with 
        // unknown message types.
    }
}
```

Now we can register implementations as follows:

```
public static class MessageHandlerServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMessageHandlers(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        void RegisterHandler<TMessageType, THandler>() 
            where TMessageType : class
            where THandler : IMessageHandler<TMessageType>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<TMessageType>();
            services.AddSingleton(
                serviceProvider => new MessageHandlerWrapper<TMessageType>(serviceProvider.GetService<THandler>())
            );
        }

        // MessageTypeOneHandler is the implementation of IMessageHandler<MessageTypeOne>
        RegisterHandler<MessageTypeOne, MessageTypeOneHandler>();
        RegisterHandler<MessageTypeTwo, MessageTypeTwoHandler>();

        // some string constants for message types would be better.
        services.AddSingleton<IMessageHandlerFactory>(serviceProvider =>
        {
            var factory = new MessageHandlerFactory();
            factory.RegisterHandler("messagetypeone",
                serviceProvider.GetService<MessageHandlerWrapper<MessageTypeOne>>);
            factory.RegisterHandler("messagetypetwo",
                serviceProvider.GetService<MessageHandlerWrapper<MessageTypeTwo>>);
            return factory;
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IMessageHandler, MessageRouter>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

Having done all of this, does it seem a bit complex? It does to me, but I still consider it worth the effort. Why?

- The message handlers are type safe instead of allowing `object` to propagate through the code. We're containing it like a disease. We can create simple, testable, single-responsibility  classes that implement `IMessageHandler<TMessage>`.
- Everything gets resolved from the container. That means the message handlers could all have their own unique dependencies, and that would be okay.
- No reflection. It's not that reflection is evil, but once we go down that road it seems to get worse.
- There is a clear path forward for the you or the next developer if you need to add handlers for more types. Even if they have no idea how to register the handlers and they don't do it, the exceptions will give them a clear path forward, showing them what they need to do. If it's registered it will get resolved. If it's not, the factory will throw an exception.

Finally, all of this is testable, even the factory. If the message types were an `enum` you could just run one test to ensure that there's a handler for every type.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("MessageTypeOne")]
[DataRow("MessageTypeTwo")]
public void FactoryResolvesMessageHandlers(string messageType)
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddMessageHandlers();
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var factory = provider.GetService<IMessageHandlerFactory>();
    var handler = factory.GetHandler(messageType);
    Assert.IsNotNull(handler);
}
```

Comment: Another thought - consider how much simpler all of this becomes if there's any way you can avoid having your message typed as `object` in the first place. To me, that's where the complexity comes in. But I've had to work through this pattern a few times, where some string identifies the type - maybe the message is JSON or something - and there's no choice but to write the code to bridge from `object` to something generic.

Comment: thank you so much for that, it will take me a while to work through. You are right, it's json and cannot be changed, so a necessary evil. This looks great!

Comment: In that case, the deserialization might make sense in `MessageHandlerWrapper<TMessage>`. Instead of `object` for the message content you could just leave it as a string. Right where the example above casts the message `object` as `TMessage` you could deserialize the JSON instead.

Comment: I'm working through this and have a question about what `// MessageTypeOneHandler is the implementation of IMessageHandler<MessageTypeOne>` is in your comments above?  What purpose does this serve as I'm struggling to understand, sorry. Where does this implementation come from? My intention is to just use Newtonsoft's json class to deserialize the string into the specific message class, e.g. MessageType1.

Comment: This means that once you've determined the concrete type, like `MessageTypeOne` or `Type2Message`, you'll need a class that implements `IMessageHandler<Type2Message>`. I didn't include an implementation of that because I don't know what happens downstream when you actually process the message after deserialziing it. (I'm also working up a separate self-answered version of this because it's a common problem, and by doing that the answer will more closely match the question.)

Comment: Ah, OK. Well in this case all that will happen is that the deserialized message will (now in its concrete form) be written to the relevant db table for subsequent processing. This app is really just a service to dequeue items and write them to a small db to allow another web api to pull items from that db and do something funky with them. I haven't got to that part of the app yet, but in my mind it was just a single class that was taking in a <T> model (whichever one of the message types it has deserialized into) and writing it to the relevant db table.

Comment: So in that case you could have a class that implements `IMessageHandler<TypeA>`, and that class does exactly that - it reads the properties of the message and writes them to a table. Another class implements `IMessageHandler<TypeB>` and writes different properties to a different table.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Been on other stuff and struggling to get this implemented. Have added a section at bottom of OP to show where there is one sticking point.